# Android: Open file in local network

Tags: android, file, networking, download, lan

I'm trying to create a program that's send SMSs every x minutes, using a .txt file located in a shared folder on my LAN network, I can't find how to catch this file...
I want to read it remotely or at least download it to my SDcard to read it after.

I tryed to solve it with few ways, but no one worked

```
File f = new File("file://192.168.2.106/Users/Maxime.test.txt");
```

or:

```
String textSource = "\\\\192.168.2.106\\Users\\Maxime\\test.txt";
textUrl = new URL(textSource);
```

My sharing does not requires a password and it's visible with ES Explorator

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: See the wiktionary examples (there are two) in the sdk samples directory.  Also declare internet permission and realize your device will have to be on wifi, not on the mobile network.

Comment: My phone is in the WIfi network, the only error i get is an unfound file, and the internet permission is declared